# Solving a system of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I cannot solve the following partial derivative equation

$$\begin{cases} -\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial x}+B_1(x,y) = y \\
~\\
-\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial y}+B_2(x,y) = -w^2 \sin(x)-ay\\
~\\
\frac{\partial B_1(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial B_2(x,y)}{\partial y}=0
\end{cases}$$

where $\omega$ and $a$ are parameters.

(If you are curious where I got this equation from, it comes from a Hemlholtz decomposition in a two-dimentional space).

I have no idea how to solve this equation to obtain $\phi, B_1$ and $B_2$.

I even could not solve it using mathematica:

```
DSolve[{
    -D[v[x, y], x] + Ba[x, y] == y,
    -D[v[x, y], y] + Bb[x, y] == -w^2 Sin[x] - a y, 
    D[Ba[x, y], x] + D[Bb[x, y], y] == 0
 }, {v[x, y], Ba[x, y],Bb[x, y]},
 {x, y}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{cases} -\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial x}+B_1(x,y) = y \\
~\\
-\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial y}+B_2(x,y) = -w^2 \sin(x)-ay\\
~\\
\frac{\partial B_1(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial B_2(x,y)}{\partial y}=0
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases} B_1(x,y) = y +\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial x} \quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial B_1(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial^2\phi(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\\
~\\
B_2(x,y) = -w^2 \sin(x)-ay+\frac{\partial\phi(x,y)}{\partial y}\quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial B_2(x,y)}{\partial y}=-a+\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y)}{\partial y^2}\\
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{\partial B_1(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial B_2(x,y)}{\partial y}=0\quad\implies\quad \frac{\partial^2\phi(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=a \tag 1$$
The general solution of the associated homogeneous PDE is 
$\quad\phi_h=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)\quad$ with arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$.

An obvious particular solution of the inhomogeneous PDE is $\quad \phi_p=\frac{a}{4}(x^2+y^2)\quad$ As a consequence, the solution of Eq.$(1)$ can be expressed on the form $\phi=\phi_h+\phi_p$ :
$$\phi(x,y)=f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)+\frac{a}{4}(x^2+y^2)$$

And then: $\quad\begin{cases} B_1(x,y) = y +f'(x+iy)+g'(x-iy)+\frac{a}{2}x\\
~\\
B_2(x,y) = -w^2 \sin(x)-ay+i\,f'(x+iy)-i\,g'(x-iy)+\frac{a}{2}y\\
\end{cases}$

where $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are arbitrary differentiable functions.

$f'(X)=\frac{df(X)}{dX}$ and $g'(X)=\frac{dg(X)}{dX}\quad$ , with respectively $X=x+i\,y$ and $X=x-i\,y$ .

Comment: Does it mean that $f$ and $g$ are dealing with complex numbers? To avoid them, can someone simple assume they are both zero?

Comment: One can assume any function one want, for example $f$ and $g$ could be nul or any constant. But this would reduce the infinite choice of possible solutions.. You also can assume that $g=f$ any function, which eliminate the imaginary part. But, again this reduces the choice of possible solutions. To be as rigorous as possible, do not assume something, but determine the convenient functions $f$ and $g$ according to the boundary conditions. If the problem is real, the derived functions $f,g$ will be so that the solution will spontaneously leads to real solution.